# Xamarin Cross Platform: UI is reset after sleep and resume

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, mobile

My application sometimes resets the UI into the initial UI state just like after the first initialization.

The event is occurred when I use another application while the problematic application is sent to background / is sleeping. Then when I change back to the problematic application, it displays the initial state of UI (The initial state of the main page).

I suppose I need to save its state before I minimize the application on `OnSleep()` event and restore it back on `OnResume()` event.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would read up Android activity life cycle, but all it sounds like you need to do is override `OnPause()` to save whatever information and `OnResume()` to load it.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? If you haven't, could you please offer some detailed codes of your project?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using global variable to store whether the application is still running or not.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if(Config.Config._RunningGetLocationThread == true)
        {
            lbl_Title.Text = "Tracker is running...";
            btn_StartTracking.Text = "Stop Tracking!";
        }
        else
        {
            btn_StartTracking.Text = "Start Tracking!";
            lbl_Title.Text = "Tracker is not running";
        }
    }
```

`Config.Config._RunningGetLocationThread == true` is the global variable and set to true when the application is first started.

I think there should be a better way to save the state of the UI elements. If anyone know the best way to save state UI elements, please share here.